# How to delete relational rows in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have Two table (Invoices-Receipts), every invoice have more than receipt (one to many relation)

In WPF if I want To delete all Receipts for a specific Invoice in one step, How can I do that ?

I have tried this:

```
     foreach (var item in _invoice.Receipts)
        _invoice.Receipts.Remove(item);
```

but it didn't work :(

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete an item from `Receipts` collection (is it a `List<Receipts>` ?) while you're enumerating it. For this reason, your code doesn't work.

Create a collection of the items you want to remove in this way:

```
var itemsToRemove = new List<Receipts>();

foreach (var item in _invoice.Receipts)
{
   if(condition)
   {
       itemsToRemove.Add(item);
   }
}
```

and then use the [`RemoveAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) method to remove them from your `_invoice.Receipts`:

```
_invoice.Receipts.RemoveAll(x => itemsToRemove.Contains(x));
```